# What import for the WebDriverInitialize function?

Tags: java, function, selenium, webdriver

I have a test plan in a csv file "testplan.csv" :

```
Name;File;Description;Navigator
test de connection;testcases\\testcase2.csv;Connection à Workday;CHROME
```

Which call another csv which describe a test case "testcase2.csv" :

```
KeyWork;Parameter 1;Parameter 3;Parameter3
CHANGEPAGE;Home - Workday;;
```

The keywords can be read in the file MOTCLE_AUTOMATISATION.java :

```
public class MOTSCLES_AUTOMATISATION {

public static Connection motCle(WebDriver driver, Connection connection, String motCle, String[] params) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InterruptedException, IOException, XmlException, SoapUIException{


    /* ### WORKDAY ### */
    AccueilPage AccueilPage2 = PageFactory.initElements(driver, AccueilPage.class);
    HomePage HomePage2 = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);

    switch (motCle){
    case "ALLER":
        System.out.println(" - Accès page : " + params[1]);
        driver.get(params[1]);
        break;
    case "CONNECTERWORKDAY":
        AccueilPage2.LogInWorkday_Action(params[1], params[2]);
        break;
    case "CHANGEPAGE":
        HomePage2.SwitchWindow(params[1]);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("ERROR : " + params[0]);
        break;
    }

    return connection;
}
}
```

The csv are read in the file MOTEUR_AUTOMATISATION.java :

```
public class MOTEUR_AUTOMATISATION {

/* LECTURE DES PROPERTIES */
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("fr.AUTOMATISATION.properties.config");

/* DECLARATIONS PREALABLES */
private static WebDriver driver = null;
public static Connection connection = null;
int indexTest =2; //variable permettant de choisir la premiere ligne du fichier ResultatExecution.xls 
public FileOutputStream out; //variable permettant de remplir le fichier ResultatExecution.xls 
public Workbook wb;//variable permettant de remplir le fichier ResultatExecution.xls 
public Sheet s;//variable permettant de remplir le fichier ResultatExecution.xls 
public Row myRow;//variable permettant de remplir le fichier ResultatExecution.xls 
public CSVReader reader;//variable permettant de remplir le fichier ResultatExecution.xls 

@BeforeSuite
public void debutSuite() throws FileNotFoundException{
    /* CREATION DU RAPPORT D'EXECUTION */
    // create a new file
    out = new FileOutputStream("ResultatExecution.xls");
    // create a new workbook
    wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    // create a new sheet
    s = wb.createSheet();
    // créer une ligne de à l'index 2 dans la feuille Excel
    myRow = null; 
}

/* LECTURE DU PLAN DE TEST*/
@DataProvider(name = "testPlan")
public Object[][] motCles() throws IOException {

    //Lecture du plan de test avec Open CSV
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(bundle.getString("autom.testplanlien")), ';', '"', 1);
    int i = 0;
    List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();
    Object testPlan[][]= new Object[allRows.size()][4];
    for(String[] row : allRows){
        testPlan[i][0] = row[0];
        testPlan[i][1] = row[1];
        testPlan[i][2] = row[2];
        testPlan[i][3] = row[3];
        i++;
        }
    reader.close();
    return testPlan;
    }

/* INTERPRETATION DU PLAN DE TEST */
@Test(dataProvider = "testPlan")
public void testCas(String nomTest, String lienTest, String descTest, String navTest) throws Exception {

    /* INITIALISATION DES VARIABLES */

    /* PARAMETRAGE DES DRIVERS */
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");

    /* LECTURE DU FICHIER DE TEST */
    reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(lienTest), ';', '"', 1);
    List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();      

    System.out.println("###################################################");
    System.out.println("##### TEST : " + nomTest);
    System.out.println("##### DESCRIPTION : " + descTest);
    System.out.println("##### NAVIGATEUR : " + navTest);
    System.out.println("###################################################");
    System.out.println("");

    /* SELECTION DU NAVIGATEUR DE TEST */
    switch(navTest.toUpperCase()){
    case "CHROME":
        ChromeOptions o = new ChromeOptions();
        o.addArguments("disable-extensions");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(o);
        break;
    case "FIREFOX":
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        break;
    case "IE":
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        break;
    case "InternetExplorer":
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        break;
    default :
        System.out.println(" - Le navigateur choisi n'est pas supporté " );
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(" - Ouverture d'une instance de " + navTest.toUpperCase());

    /* PARAMETRAGE DU DRIVER */
    //driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("tps.implicitlywait")), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("tps.pagetoload")), TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    /* INTERPRETATION DES MOTS-CLES */
    for(String[] row : allRows){
        /* Ecriture dans le fichier de compte-rendu d'execution */
        myRow = s.createRow(indexTest);
        myRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(lienTest);
        myRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(row[0]);
        myRow.createCell(2).setCellValue("KO");
        indexTest++;
        connection=MOTSCLES_AUTOMATISATION.motCle(driver, connection, row[0],row);
        myRow.createCell(2).setCellValue("OK"); //si le mot-clef s'execute bien jusqu'au bout alors OK sinon il reste a KO
    }   
}


/* FONCTION POUR SE CONNECTER A UNE BDD */
public static Connection getConnection(String URL, String userName, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    System.out.println(" - Connexion SQL en cours...");
    Class.forName("COM.ibm.db2os390.sqlj.jdbc.DB2SQLJDriver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, userName, password);
    System.out.println(" - Connexion SQL OK : " + userName + "@" + URL);
   return connection;
}


@AfterTest
public void finTest() throws IOException {
    /* FIN DU TEST */
    System.out.println(" - FIN DU TEST - ");
    //reader.close();
    //driver.close();
}


@AfterSuite
public void finSuite() throws IOException {
    /* FERMETURE EXCEL */
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
}
}
```

For the testcase2.csv, the KEYWORK script use this java file "HomePage.java"

```
public class HomePage {

//##############définition des élements (boutons, listes, saisie)s##############
//@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "div[data-automation-id='popup'] > input")
//public WebElement TB_RESEARCH;

public void SwitchWindow(String windowName){
    System.out.println(" ----- We are going to the Home Page");
    Utility.getHandleToWindow(windowName);
    System.out.println(" ---------- Here we are");

}
}
```

The getHangleToWindow function is defined in the Utility.java file :

```
public class Utility {

public static WebDriver getHandleToWindow(String title){

    //parentWindowHandle = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
    WebDriver popup = null;
    MyWebDriver WebDriverInitialize = new MyWebDriver ();
    Set<String> windowIterator = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandles();
    System.err.println("No of windows :  " + windowIterator.size());

    for (String s : windowIterator) {

        String windowHandle = s; 
        popup = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().switchTo().window(windowHandle);
        System.out.println("Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Window Url : " + popup.getCurrentUrl());
        if (popup.getTitle().equals(title) ){
            System.out.println("Selected Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
            return popup;

        }

    }

        System.out.println("Window Title :" + popup.getTitle());
        System.out.println();
        return popup;

    }
}
```

And it uses the kushal response, for MyWebDriver.java file :

```
public class MyWebDriver {

WebDriver driver =null;

public void MyWebDriver(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
    this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

public WebDriver getDriver(){
    return this.driver;
}

}
```

Comment: So you want to switch between windows ?

Comment: Add the current `import`s to your post.

Comment: In fact, I need to test an application. Point is, at every connexion they send me a code by SMS. So I wanna begin my test manually for the connexion, and continue the test automatically. So I need to get the window after the connection. I just can't launch the webadress. Am I clear ? Sorry for my english

Comment: What do you mean by current import RO_engineer ?

Comment: @celianou , copy the first lines from your file and add them to this Stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Set`  import is `import java.util.Set;`  and for second part I don't think there is any import for this; it looks like this is a borrowed code from somewhere which makes use of `WebDriverInitialize` which is a class or an object of a class having a getDriver() function, you can add following class into your project:

```
package yourPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class MyWebDriver {

    WebDriver driver =null;

    public void MyWebDriver(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\Eclipse\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();

    }

    public WebDriver getDriver(){
        return this.driver;


    }
}
```

**Updated Utility class :**

```
package fr.WORKDAY.utilities;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import java.util.Set;

public class Utility {

public static WebDriver getHandleToWindow(String title, WebDriver driver){

    //parentWindowHandle = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
    WebDriver popup = null;
    Set<String> windowIterator = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.err.println("No of windows :  " + windowIterator.size());

    for (String s : windowIterator) {

        String windowHandle = s; 
        popup = driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
        System.out.println("Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Window Url : " + popup.getCurrentUrl());
        if (popup.getTitle().equals(title) ){
            System.out.println("Selected Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
            return popup;

        }

    }

        System.out.println("Window Title :" + popup.getTitle());
        System.out.println();
        return popup;

    }
}
```

Comment: "Cannot use this in a static content" and about public void WebDriverInitialize, "this method has a constructor name" (just a warning for this one)

Comment: You'' have to make WebDriverInitialize an object of myWebDriver class before using it in your class

Comment: No error, just two warning "import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions i never used
" and "this method has a constructor name" <- about the MyWebDriver method

Comment: How to make webdriverinitialize an object ?

Comment: `MyWebDriver webdriverinitialize = new MyWebDriver ();` in your utility class.

Comment: Because of it I have "THe method getDriver is undefined for the type MyWebDriver"

Comment: but there is a `getDriver` function in `MyWebDriver` class where are you declaring `MyWebDriver webdriverinitialize = new MyWebDriver ();` ?

Comment: two things 1) have you included MyWebDriver class in your project, if yes,  at which line do you receive the error?

Comment: It opens a chrome window (why ???) and doing nothing. I failed somewhere. For your question, yes, and in fact I have no error

Comment: It's in a csv that I am calling :)

Comment: It will open a new Web browser window because we are creating a new Instance of `chromedriver` within `MyWebDriver` class' constructor as `this.driver = new ChromeDriver();`

Comment: Try using Updated `Utilities class` from my updated answer but you'll have to provide `WebDriver` as argument to it.

Comment: I doing shit I thing, I don't know what I will have in finish... I updated my mainpost

Comment: Okay.. so your whole project is working now? what about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250980/error-in-java-with-selenium-expected-object-undefined-undefined-to-be-a-stri

Comment: Yes, I deleted all the project and begin again by a good installation, configuration etc. And I am trying to work more properly now

Comment: Hmm... Another question. How can I press the enter key with selenium ?

Comment: You can use `sendKeys()` to do that `driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your xpath")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER");`

Comment: I forgot to tell you one thing your password and username are visible here in this post under error trace : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250980/error-in-java-with-selenium-expected-object-undefined-undefined-to-be-a-stri edit the post and remove them ASAP